# Beginning VSTO Development

Tags: .net, vsto, ms-office

I'm quite confused with what are the necessary tools for [VSTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office) develpment. Specifically I want to manipulate Excel 2003/2007 documents programmatically. I did quite a lot of [VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) before, if you want to relate any answer to that.

Few questions I have about VSTO:

1. Can I use Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition C#/C++ for this?
2. Do I need to have .NET framework installed?
3. Does the resulting VSTO program need to have a copy of Office installed in the same system to run?

Direct links to the relevant tools/plugins/IDE will be appreciated.

Note: I'm totally new to VSTO and .NET but an Office power user. I have experience with COM programming.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yeah, it can get confusing, especially given the skip-level naming conventions, etc. Essentially, you'll need:

- Full version (not Express) of Visual
  Studio and the .NET version you're targetting.
- One of the VSTO run times (VSTO 2003, VSTO
  2005, VSTO 2005 SE, VSTO 2008, VSTO
  2010). For what your asking, VSTO
  2005 SE is probably your best bet.
- When distributing your app, you'll
  need more, like the PIAs and the .NET version you've targetted. For VSTO 2010, you don't need the PIAs (just what you're using will be packaged with your app automatically).

A couple of tips:

- Going from the VBE inside of Office
  to VSTO should be a smooth-ish move
  if you've used .NET to much extent.
- The VSTO versions of the object
  models for any given program (Excel,
  PowerPoint, etc.) there may be a few
  more ways of doing things that are
  different/better than in the VBA
  version of the object model. For
  example, the Bookmark control for
  Word in VSTO 2008 is not the same as
  the one that is native to one
  accessed via VBA.
- Distributing your app can be a pain.
  This is the very reason that that VSTO for Visual Studio 2010 does not require you
  to include the full interop (PIA) files
  with your package.
- Targetting different versions of
  Office with the same solution is not
  officially supported for pre-VSTO 2010. There are ways
  around this issue that some folks
  have talked about, but you won't get
  much support from MSFT on it.

There are some sites that you should take a look at:

- [**Requirements VSTO solutions**](http://xldennis.wordpress.com/2007/04/08/requirements-vsto-solutions/).
  This is older, but is helpful to read
  regarding the differences between the
  2005 and 2005 SE versions. [**This
  one**](http://blogs.msdn.com/andreww/archive/2008/04/02/vsto-loader-and-runtime-components.aspx) is also decent in that it
  includes the 2008 version.
- [**Online resources for VSTO**](http://www.excelkb.com/article.aspx?id=10185). This
  is a good 'jump' site for learning
  more about VSTO.
- [**Getting Started (Visual Studio Tools
  for Office)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23cw517s(VS.80).aspx). This, and it's
  sister link pages, are good jump
  pages. Not that useful if you're just
  coming up to speed with VSTO, but
  good for a little bit later.
- [**Can you build one add-in for
  multiple versions of Office?**](http://blogs.msdn.com/andreww/archive/2007/06/15/can-you-build-one-add-in-for-multiple-versions-of-office.aspx).
  This is older, but discusses some of
  the issues around building for
  multiple versions of Office.
- [**This site**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/dd164303.aspx) used to be better
  organized, but I've always found that
  videos are a very fast way to learn.
  Most of these videos use one version
  of VSTO.

Finally, to save the best for last, this is the book I read when I was just starting out and it was very helpful: [***VSTO for Mere Mortals(TM): A VBA Developer's Guide to Microsoft Office Development Using Visual Studio 2005 Tools for Office***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321426711)

Comment: yea.. thanks for taking the time to explain in detail.

i'm a bit sad to know i that I express cant work though.

Comment: great answer Mr Otaku (as always)

Comment: Could you share some resources about distributing vsto application?

Comment: Sorry, it's been too many years. I wish I had more for you

Answer (score 5):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) is an Excel compatible spreadsheet component for .NET which will work with Visual Studio Express editions, requires .NET 2.0 or higher, does not require Office or Excel to be installed, and does permit royalty free distribution to an unlimited number of client and / or server computers.

You can see live samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Comment: spreadsheet gear for .net is great. SO is so cool - we get to see people posting here that are doing some really great work. so far i've seen joel, jesse liberty and now you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create excel with Express Edition using this [Excel .NET component](http://www.devtriogroup.com/ExcelJetcell/Default.aspx). It doesn't require VSTO, ADO or MS Excel automation.

Excel Jetcell .NET component allows to read write excel spreadsheet.
Here you can find many [Excel VB.NET and C# examples](http://www.devtriogroup.com/ExcelJetcell/Samples/Default.aspx). For example see VB.NET code to create excel spreadsheet from array:

```
Imports DTG.Spreadsheet
...
Dim WBook = New ExcelWorkbook()
WBook.Worksheets.Add("ArrayValues")
For i As Short = 0 To 10
   For j As Short = 0 To 10
      WBook.Worksheets(0).Cells[i,j].Value = arr(i,j)
      j = j + 1
   Next j
   i = i + 1
Next i
WBook.WriteXLSX("ExcelSpreadsheet.xlsx")
```