# Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) - Looking for some User Guide

Tags: excel, visual-studio, vsto, excel-addins

I'm looking for some user guide about **Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)** specially oriented to **Excel Add-ins** programming.

I have installed **Visual Studio 2013** and **Microsoft Office 2013** on my computer.

Do you know about some **user guide**, **tutorial** or **manual** preferably in **PDF** about **VSTO**?.

Best regards!

Comment: Do you have VS2013 Express or the full version? Express does not support VSTO.

Comment: I have the full version

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063866/beginning-vsto-development at the bottom you have links to Guides and Starting with VSTO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Excel Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386107.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) section in MSDN provides all the required information. I'd suggest starting from the [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx) article.